# SQL Syntax Error Creating Table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am getting the following error when I try to create a table in an SQL database:

```
Failed to create table 'references'
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near 'references(referenceID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
referenceText VARCHAR(255)'
```

Here is the code making the table:

```
public void createReferencesTable() {
    System.out.println("Creating table '" + REFERENCE_TABLE + "'...");
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE " + REFERENCE_TABLE + "("
                + REFERENCE_ID + " BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                + REFERENCE_TEXT + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + REFERENCE_TWEET + " BIGINT NOT NULL,"
                + "PRIMARY KEY (" + REFERENCE_ID + ")"
                + ")");
        System.out.println("Table '" + REFERENCE_TABLE + "' created");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create table '" + REFERENCE_TABLE + "'");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { 
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the declarations of the variables used:

```
public static final String REFERENCE_TABLE = "references";
public static final String REFERENCE_ID = "referenceID";
public static final String REFERENCE_TEXT = "referenceText";
public static final String REFERENCE_TWEET = "referenceTweet";
```

Also, I am creating two tables before this one that successfully work with basically the exact same syntax as this one, which is failing. Also, the MySQL server I am putting this databases into is fresh and just set-up, so there shouldn't be any configuration issues, as my program is connecting to the database successfully.

My question is: Why is this giving an error?

Notes: I have tried to do the reference ID line with an identity, but that did not make any difference. As I said before, the two functions each creating a table before this used exactly the same syntax, but gave no errors and successfully created their tables.

Comment: Try adding a space to `stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE " + REFERENCE_TABLE + "("` so that it's `" ("`.

Comment: The first thing you should check when you're dynamically generating SQL – or dynamically generating code in *any* language – is ... the code that's been dynamically generated. Instead of passing the expression or statement that generates the SQL directly to `stmt.executeUpdate`, assign the (string) value to a variable and then print the variable to your console output.

Comment: Jacob - Thank you, but Juergen's answer solved my problem.

Comment: Kenny - I will definitely keep that in mind when debugging SQL in the future, as I am new to it I'm unfamiliar with the language and needed a quick solution for this issue. However, I will certainly do that from now on. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`references` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. Either use backticks to escape it or use another name.

```
stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE `" + REFERENCE_TABLE + "` ("
                                 ^-----------------------^-----------here
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something so intuitive that I couldn't find it. Thanks again.